# Cocos2d-x schedule a call

Tags: cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-3.0

I'm trying to schedule a call for a function, the function is changeScene() and it's never being called

Any idea what am I doing wrong?

Cocos-2d-x 3.0

```
#include "LoadingScene.h"
LoadingScene::LoadingScene(){}

LoadingScene::~LoadingScene(){}

bool LoadingScene::init() {
    return Scene::init();
}

void LoadingScene::onEnter(){
    // add background to current scene
    Sprite *background = Sprite::create("splash.png");
    Size visibleSize = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleSize();
    Point origin = Director::getInstance()->getVisibleOrigin();
    background->setPosition(origin.x + visibleSize.width/2, origin.y + visibleSize.height/2);
    this->addChild(background);

    // start ansyc method load the atlas.png
    Director::getInstance()->getTextureCache()->addImageAsync("atlas.png", CC_CALLBACK_1(LoadingScene::loadingCallBack, this));
}

void LoadingScene::loadingCallBack(Texture2D *texture){
    AtlasLoader::getInstance()->loadAtlas("atlas.txt", texture);
    this->scheduleOnce(schedule_selector(LoadingScene::changeScene), 2.0f);
}

void LoadingScene::changeScene(float dt) {
    auto scene = WelcomeScene::create();
    TransitionScene *transition = TransitionFade::create(1, scene);
    Director::getInstance()->replaceScene(transition);
}
```

Comment: You really haven't given us enough information. Do you make it into `loadingCallback`? Why not put a few `std::cout` statements in `loadingCallback` and `changeScene` to help debug.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in `LoadingScene::onEnter()` you must get the absolute path to your file:

```
string fullPath = FileUtils::getInstance()->fullPathForFilename("atlas.png");
Director::getInstance()->getTextureCache()->addImageAsync(fullPath, CC_CALLBACK_1(LoadingScene::loadingCallBack, this));
```

The method searches in a number of paths which can be extended. See description of `FileUtils::fullPathForFilename()`

Answer (score 0):

You need to add CCLayer::onEnter();

```
    void LoadingScene::loadingCallBack(Texture2D *texture){
     CCLayer::onEnter();//add this line
    AtlasLoader::getInstance()->loadAtlas("atlas.txt", texture);
    this->scheduleOnce(schedule_selector(LoadingScene::changeScene), 2.0f);
}
```